# chrome.runtime.onMessage undefined in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**manifest,json**

```
{
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "file:///*"
    ],
    "css": ["mystyles.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "myscript.js"]
}],
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead",
    "activeTab",
    "identity",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "*.png"
]}
```

**content script**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
console.log(message);});
```

**chrome console**

[image: in chrome console]

my chrome version : 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) 
why chrome.runtime.onMessage is undefined in content_script?
Please tell me how to solve this problem~:)

Whether there are other ways to achieve that background sendMessage to content script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.onMessage` is not a function indeed, it's an `Event` object that provides `addListener` function method:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: thanks! I tried to use `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`.The Console is not throw error again,but it looks like no effect.Content script is still not accepted message from background script

Comment: Content scripts aren't reloaded automatically when you reload your extension so you need to reload the tab.

Comment: I'm sure I've done it.but it still no effect.Can you give me some examples of what you realized?

Comment: There are tons of examples. Simply debug the content script and the background page in devtools.

Comment: onMessage is still undefined for me (

Comment: Had the same issue... complete restart of chrome did the trick

Comment: I'm showing onMessage undefined too. But it's in a script my content script loaded by adding a <script> tag.

Comment: @Jerinaw it's not a content script but a normal page script so it can't use extension messaging, [more info](/a/9517879).